# Can't Change Labels for Dynamically-Added Form Fields Using wtforms, append_entry() and FieldList(FormField())

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm struggling to change the labels for FieldList subforms added dynamically using .append_entry(). I can successfully change the labels for the overall form, and for directly in front of each individual field, but I still get a bullet and a default label-0, label-1, label-2 etc. above each successive field instance and I can't rename it or get rid of it.

I am creating a form that gathers characteristics about a varying number of communities and militants that exist in a varying number of regions. I have one overall form and four subforms. For example, if I have 2 regions and 3 communities, the first part of my form called regionpercent asks for the percent of each region's population that identifies with each community, looking something like this:

Region 1
Percent Community 1:
Percent Community 2:
Percent Community 3:

Region 2
Percent Community 1:
Percent Community 2:
Percent Community 3:

So I need to change the sublabels for regionpercent to ['Region1`<br>`Percent Community 1:', 'Percent Community 2:', 'Percent Community 3:', '`<br>`Region 2`<br>`Percent Community 1:', 'Percent Community 2:', 'Percent Community 3:']. But right now, before each of the six fields I have a "regionpercent-0", "regionpercent-1" and so on.

The main form is called ThirdForm().

Here are my form classes:

```
class RegionForm2(FlaskForm):
    x = FloatField(validators=[InputRequired()])

    def __init__(self, labels=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if labels is None:
            labels = ['percent of the population:']
        self.x.label = Label(self.x.id, labels[0])

class GrievancesForm(FlaskForm):
    box = BooleanField(validators=None)

    def __init__(self, labels=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if labels is None:
            labels = ['Grievance?:']
        self.box.label = Label(self.box.id, labels[0])

class AffiliationsForm(FlaskForm):
    boxm = BooleanField(validators=None)

    def __init__(self, labels=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if labels is None:
            labels = ['Affiliation?:']
        self.boxm.label = Label(self.boxm.id, labels[0])

class MilitantForm2(FlaskForm):
    reg = BooleanField(validators=None)

    def __init__(self, labels=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if labels is None:
            labels = ['Active?:']
        self.reg.label = Label(self.reg.id, labels[0])

class ThirdForm(FlaskForm):
    regionpercent = FieldList(FormField(RegionForm2))
    grievances = FieldList(FormField(GrievancesForm))
    affiliations = FieldList(FormField(AffiliationsForm))
    milactive = FieldList(FormField(MilitantForm2))
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def __init__(self, labels=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if labels is None:
            labels = ['Percentage of Each Community Present in Each Region', 'Grievances Between Communities', 'Affiliation of Communities with Militants', 'Active Militants in Each Region']
        self['regionpercent'].label = Label(self['regionpercent'].id, labels[0])
        self['grievances'].label = Label(self['grievances'].id, labels[1])
        self['affiliations'].label = Label(self['affiliations'].id, labels[2])
        self['milactive'].label = Label(self['milactive'].id, labels[3])
```

Here is my routes.py:

```
@app.route('/page3', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page3():
    regionnames = session.get('regionnames', None)
    communitynames = session.get('communitynames', None)
    militantnames = session.get('militantnames', None)
    form = ThirdForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        regiondata = form.regionpercent.data
        return redirect(url_for('next_page'))
    for i in range(len(regionnames)*len(communitynames)):
        form.regionpercent.append_entry()
    for i in range(len(communitynames)*(len(communitynames)-1)):
        form.grievances.append_entry()
    for i in range(len(communitynames)*len(militantnames)):
        form.affiliations.append_entry()
    for i in range(len(regionnames)*len(militantnames)):
        form.milactive.append_entry()
    print('regionpercent:', form.regionpercent)
    return render_template('page3.html', title='Third Page', form=form)
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<h1> Model Parameters- Page 3</h1>
    <h3> More Properties</h3>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.regionpercent.label }}<br>
            {{ form.regionpercent(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.grievances.label }}<br>
            {{ form.grievances(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.affiliations.label }}<br>
            {{ form.affiliations(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.milactive.label }}<br>
            {{ form.milactive(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Despite manually adding labels I still see `<label for="regionpercent-0">Regionpercent-0</label>` if I print form.regionpercent.

I imported lists in my routes.py file of region, community, and militant names so that I could use them as the labels, but I haven't made it that far yet as I'm stuck on this issue. I'm optimistic that I can handle creating the label lists but not sure yet how I'll pass those lists to the classes.

I was originally trying to create a sub-sub forms, where first I would iterate over the number of communities and then iterate of the number of militants (for example), but I couldn't access the data from all of the fields using form.affiliations.data this way. So it is absolutely necessary that I change these subfield labels in order to distinguish between Community 1 and its subsections Militant1, Militant2... etc.

If its possible to remove the default subfield labels completely and add my own text between each field instance, that would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using Javascript in my HTML templates to find the labels based on their names hidden in the page. I then replaced them with the label names I prefer. For example, where the unwanted label occurring was regionpercent-0, I used the following code:

```
var label = document.querySelector('label[for="regionpercent-0"]') !==null;
if (label) {
    var label = document.querySelector('label[for="regionpercent-0"]');
    label.textContent = '{{ region_percent_list[0] }}';
}
```

where region_percent_list[0] is the variable name for the actual label that I wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your struggling.

Each item in the list uses the Label class, which has the field_id and text attributes.

Then you can edit text from the label field as follows:

```
for i in range(len(regionnames)*len(communitynames)):
    form.regionpercent.append_entry()
    form.regionpercent[i].label.text = 'Region {}'.format(i)  # include this line
```

Obviously there are other changes, but I think that is enough to understand the logic.

It helped me a lot.